# discord.py questions about channels messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

im wondering if i could message more channels at once by id ( general, announcements, giveaways etc.)
This is my error right now but i cannot figure it out why is not working.

```
ERROR: Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 17, in on_ready
    member = await bot.fetch_user(i)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 1384, in fetch_user
    data = await self.http.get_user(user_id)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 250, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10013): Unknown User
```

and the code is [in the pastebin](https://pastebin.com/quVxLiDR):

Comment: Please but the code in a code in a codebloc, not on a pastebin. [Here's how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: I gave you an answer that should work, check it. Ask me in the comments if something went wrong.

Comment: @Kyrela i could put the code in a code block because it gave me an error that is not formatted correctly.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO it worked
now if i want to dm some users by ids
can i do that?

Comment: @seek, I've answered your question. If it works you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fetch

---

The problem is that you used `fetch_user()` instead of `fetch_channel` at line 17.

---

You should try to use this code:

```
channel = await bot.fetch_channel(i)
await channel.send("...")
```

---

Your error is that into your `.json` file there are some IDs, and they're channels' IDs.
Using channels' IDs like members' IDs will obviously raise an error.
In that case your error is saying that the member with the ID given to `fetch_user()` doesn't exist.

## Suggestion

---

You should use exception handling to remove from the file  the channels which are not still existing.
For example:

```
with open(r"C:\\Your\Path\to\file.json", 'r+') as File:
    data = json.load(File)
for ID in data:
    try:
        channel = bot.fetch_channel(ID)
    except discord.errors.NotFound: # Raised if ID doesn't exist anymore
        data.remove(ID)
        os.remove(r"C:\\Your\Path\to\file.json")
        with open(r"C:\\Your\Path\to\file.json", 'w') as File:
            json.dump(data, File)
```

## DM users

---

If you want to DM some users from their IDs, you just have to do like this:

```
with open(r"C:\\IDs.json", 'r') as File:
    data = json.load(File)
for ID in data:
    user = await bot.fetch_user(ID)
    await user.send("Your message")
```

Remember this can raise an exception, because some users don't allow bots to DM them.